# What does \processtable{}, and where can I learn about what it does?

Tags: tables

LaTeX Companion does not mention `\processtable{}` command. It seems to obviate the need for `\caption{}`... where do I go to learn more?

Comment: Can you provide an example of its usage from the LaTeX Companion?

Comment: @Werner The question specifically says it's not in TLC! I guess you mean 'Can you say where you've seen this command?'.

Comment: @JosephWright: Yikes, and I agree with the correction.

Comment: apa and apa6  have `\processtables` (with an `s`) no package in my full texlive 2015 had `\processtable` as far as I can see

Comment: This is coming out of http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/LIMAONE/LaTeX-Table-v1.0.6/examples/examples.pdf.  "October 23, 2010  LaTeX::Table
is a Perl module that provides functionality for an intuitive and easy
generation of LaTeX tables.  It ships with some predened good looking table styles. This module supports multipage tables via the xtab and the
longtable package and publication quality tables with the booktabs
package.  It also supports the tabularx and tabulary packages  for  nicer  fixed-width  tables.  ...   "

Comment: @R.Schumacher good call and the example with this command is documented as coming from the bioinformatics journal, so it seems this is a journal-specific locally defined command.

Comment: FWIW this command also appears in the IET Journal's templates and instructions as part of the cta-author class. The usage can be seen in the "CTA_Sample.tex" file.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to R. Schumacher for the initial link hint. This is a locally defined command in the class `bioinfo.cls`  which is available from here

http://www.oxfordjournals.org/our_journals/bioinformatics/for_authors/submission_online.html

Unless you are submitting a paper to that journal, you do not want to use that class.

Slightly bizarrely the class actually defines a `processtable` environment with a null end code, but then the sample document provided with the class uses
the command form.

bioinfo.cls:

```
\newenvironment{processtable}[3]{\setbox\temptbox=\hbox{{\tablesize #2}}%
\tempdime\wd\temptbox\@processtable{#1}{#2}{#3}{\tempdime}}
{\relax}
```